# The latest version of the Download installer seems to be infected with a virus

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have been using TOR browser for awhile now and am generally happy with it. But it seems there is some Generic Virus living in it and worse the version 6.5 after the upgrade and my anti-virus has eliminated the threat the shortcut loses track of where my browser live. I felt it would be good to share this information. I have Windows 10 on a Toshiba Satellite.

Comment: can you please make a password-protected RAR archive and post it's dropbox link with a password? I've occured some fake Tor and TBB distributions, so I'd like to study it a bit deeper

Comment: This is likely a false positive from your antivirus. Download a fresh copy and verify the signature to ensure that it's legitimate. If it is and your antivirus still detects it as malicious, contact your antivirus vendor to notify them of their error.

Comment: Well I have had that result several times when I try to install the software. I will try again later today (30 Jan 2017) and when the anti-virus detects the problem I will just ignore it and see what happens. But it seems awfully persistent.

Comment: Okay. Here is what has been happening. My antivirus detects a generic virus in the torbrowser-install-4.0.8_enUS.exe. This was found first on Jan 27 2017 at 4:47:34 PM EST (My time zone). As I said after the detection and removal the shortcut to the TOR Browser no longer points to my Mozilla Firefox, I get the shortcut is broken/invalid and don't work. So I remove the file and it's components and go for a fresh download and when I install the detection repeats. So it would seem that the installer is infected at the source.